# fluid dynamic helix

Tags: bezier-curves, fluid-simulation

I trying fluid simulator in Blender, and I wanted to make an animation where water flows from centre along to curve and screw along.
How setup Inflow for this result:

[image]

Comment: marked as duplicate by LukeD, Ray Mairlot, Duarte Farrajota Ramos, David :( but I can't find answer for my question. May be you can link to original?